# md-virtual-repeat with md-autocomplete implemetion

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am using md-virtual-repeat, I need to implement search option using md-autocomplete is there a way to add md-autocomplete with md-virtual-repeat, I searched through the angular material docs but I cant find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to supply an `md-virtual-repeat` object to the `md-items` attribute of an `md-autocomplete`, then the answer is unfortunately "no". I had hoped that you could since it uses an `md-virtual-repeat` under the covers to display the items, but sadly it only accepts an array or a function that returns a promise that resolves to an array. I